# vs2010 create XLL with Excel2007SDK

Tags: c++, excel, xll

I have followed the [Andrew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2007/12/09/building-an-excel-xll-in-c-c-with-vs-2008.aspx) to create XLL under vs2010 c++ and Excel2007SDK, It works fine on Excel2010. After I registered the XLL on Excel2007, it shows registered successfully but no functions can be called. Anyone can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself some trouble and try http://xll.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 1):

It was failing because I needed to install Microsoft's VC++ redistributable.  It is working now.